# How to evaluate a Julia expression from the terminal (not the REPL)?

Tags: terminal, julia

Is there a way to run a (set of) Julia commands without entering the REPL?

E.g. `julia.exe "using IJulia; notebook()"` doesn't work.

MY end goal is to be able to create a clickable batch file that allows me and others I share it with to open Jupyter without needing to worry about the command line or REPL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `-e` flag to the julia executable like this:

```
julia.exe -e "using IJulia; notebook()"
```

If you don't want the session to die after running, and you want it to give you a REPL afterwards, you can pass `-i` as:

```
julia.exe -e "using IJulia; notebook()" -i
```

This option and others is documented in the ["Getting started"](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/getting-started/) section of the documentation

Or by running the executable with the `-h` flag:

```
julia.exe -h
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition with `-e` option, `julia` also read and evaluate stdin. Thus you can also do these using shell pipes/redirections:

```
$ echo '1+1' | julia
2

$ julia <<EOF
> 1+1
> EOF
2

$ julia <<< 1+1
2
```